# Not allow user to manually launch an application

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, executable, windows-ce

I need a way to prevent the user of a windows mobile based phone to launch my application exe file directly.

I have the following scenario: My windows mobile application has two exe files, one has a shortcut in Applications Menu and the other must be hide for the user. What i want is to not allow the user to manually execute my hidden exe file, but without modifying the original file.

Answer (score 2):

Why not allow it to take some commands in at run time and if none are present (i.e the user just clicked the exe) then by default it wont run. But allow the shortcut to pass parameters to it to allow it to run.

Comment: Hello, that is how it works now. But i need a way of doing this without modifying the original exe (in most cases it would be a third party one, so i can not have access to sources).

Comment: unless you try and create a runner app which points to the other one, so any references would be to the front app rather then the actual app. Any reason why you really don't want access to the main app?

Answer (score 0):

You could rename it to .dat or something and just temporarily rename it to .exe for launching. As long as the user uses the standard WM file explorer, changing file extensions isn't possible (at least I never managed to). And if the user is determined to launch it and has enough knowledge, they'll be able to do so anyway -- unless the program itself tests who launched it, which (as I understand) is not possible because you can't modify it.